# Filtering a Block

Tags: linux, bash, shell, xml-parsing

I have multiple blocks of the below pattern

```
<APPLIANCE>
        <ID>12233</ID>
        <UUID>xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx</UUID>
        <NAME>xxxxxxx</NAME>
        <STATUS>Offline</STATUS>
</APPLIANCE>
<APPLIANCE>
        <ID>12234</ID>
        <UUID>xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx</UUID>
        <NAME>yyyyy</NAME>
        <STATUS>Offline</STATUS>
</APPLIANCE>
```

I want to extract a block with Particular ID and Particular Name.
The output should display

For example :-

```
<ID>12234</ID>
<NAME>yyyyy</NAME>
```

I wanted to do using grep, sed, awk

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sed should work for you:

```
sed -n '/<ID>12234/,/<NAME>/{//p}' file
```

But you'd better use an xml parser as [xmllint](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html) or [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) to parse valid xml files.

Comment: Can anyone explain why `{//p}` prints out only the beginning and the end of the range `/<ID>12234/,/<NAME>/`? I thought // would repeat the last match which would be the whole range in my opinion.

Comment: @marli `//` matches the same pattern as the previous address or in that case the pattern of each address of the range. To print the whole range, just remove `//`.